# Get the current route name into the component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying not to use : if(window.location) to get access to my current route.

I am working on a code where the router is already defined, and the component is already written. I am trying to access the router information from the component because I need to apply a classname depending on the route.

Here's how the router looks like:

`export const createRoutes = (dispatch, getState) => (
      <Route component={AppLayout} >
         <Route path="/" component={Home} onEnter={(nextState, replaceState) => {
            console.log('on Enter / = ', nextState);
            nextState.test = 'aaaa'; //can't seem to pass states here....
        }} />`

then in my component:

```
render() {
    //I want to access my super router or location . in fact
    // I just want to know if currentURl === '/'

    //and after reading the react-router doc 5 times - my head hurts 
    // but I still hope to get an answer here before putting a window.location
 }
`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on which version of React Router you're using you have access to different objects available on the `context` of a component.

```
MyComponent.contextTypes = {
    location: React.PropTypes.object
}
```

which will enable you to do the following

```
render() {
    if (this.context.location.pathname === '/') {
        return <h1>Index</h1>;
    } else {
        return <h2>Not index</h2>;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, finally a code snippet which is up to date !

Comment: Basically the same solution presented in a few more lines of code, may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37523743