# react-router getting this.props.location in child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

As I understand `<Route path="/" component={App} />` will gives `App` routing-related props like `location` and `params`. If my `App` component has many nested child components, how do I get the child component to have access to these props without:

- passing props from App
- using window object
- creating routes for nested child components

I thought `this.context.router` would have some information related to the routes, but `this.context.router` seems to only have some functions to manipulate the routes.

Comment: In App Component,direct nested child component can be find at this.props.children

Comment: Couldn't ask it better...

Answer (score 178, accepted):

**V6**

You can use [`useNavigate`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate), [`useLocation`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#uselocation) and [`useMatch`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usematch) in your component to get [`matchPath`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#matchpath), [`navigate`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate) and [`location`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#location) .

```
const Child = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const match = useMatch("write-the-url-you-want-to-match-here");

  return (
    <div>{location.pathname}</div>
  )
}

export default Child
```

**V5.1 & Hooks (Requires React >= 16.8)**

You can use [`useHistory`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/usehistory), [`useLocation`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/uselocation) and [`useRouteMatch`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/useroutematch) in your component to get [`match`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match), [`history`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history) and [`location`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location) .

```
const Child = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const history = useHistory();
  const match = useRouteMatch("write-the-url-you-want-to-match-here");

  return (
    <div>{location.pathname}</div>
  )
}

export default Child
```

**V4 & V5**

You can use [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) HOC in order to inject [`match`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match), [`history`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history) and [`location`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location) in your component props.

```
class Child extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    match: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    location: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    history: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }

  render() {
    const { match, location, history } = this.props

    return (
      <div>{location.pathname}</div>
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(Child)
```

**V3**

You can use [`withRouter`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/API.md#withroutercomponent-options) HOC in order to inject [`router`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/API.md#router-1), [`params`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/API.md#params), [`location`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/API.md#location), [`routes`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/API.md#routes) in your component props.

```
class Child extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const { router, params, location, routes } = this.props

    return (
      <div>{location.pathname}</div>
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(Child)
```

**Original answer**

If you don't want to use the props, you can use the context as described in [React Router documentation](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v2.8.1/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md#accessing-location)

First, you have to set up your `childContextTypes` and `getChildContext`

```
class App extends React.Component{
  
  getChildContext() {
    return {
      location: this.props.location
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <Child/>;
  }
}

App.childContextTypes = {
    location: React.PropTypes.object
}
```

Then, you will be able to access to the location object in your child components using the context like this

```
class Child extends React.Component{
   
   render() {
     return (
       <div>{this.context.location.pathname}</div>
     )
   }
   
}

Child.contextTypes = {
    location: React.PropTypes.object
 }
```

Comment: thanks for the pointer. I did not read that part of the documentation. I thought there is only ```context.router```

Comment: You ought to mention [if you want your application to be stable, don't use context. It is an experimental API and it is likely to break in future releases of React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html#why-not-to-use-context).

Comment: I'm new to React. Thus, forgive me if I'm wrong, but what's wrong with using `window.location.pathname`?

Comment: window.location is mutable so it's considered best practice not to access it, preferring to use an immutable version. Also, I think it's possible to use logical locations which differ from the window.location (at least this is true in nextjs) so it's possible to get a different location from your router than the direct window history

Comment: @ArturBarseghyan The `window` object doesn't exist if the React code is run on the server e.g. to implement server-side routing.

Comment: .what about V6?

Comment: The hooks don't seem to work for descendant components.

Answer (score 6):

If the above solution didn't work for you, you can use `import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';`

---

Using this you can export your child class as -

```
class MyApp extends Component{
    // your code
}

export default withRouter(MyApp);
```

And your class with Router -

```
// your code
<Router>
      ...
      <Route path="/myapp" component={MyApp} />
      // or if you are sending additional fields
      <Route path="/myapp" component={() =><MyApp process={...} />} />
<Router>
```

Comment: Not with react-router-dom v6 it seems.

Comment: Please provide workaround for dom v6 @Lqueryvg, during the time of writing this ans it was not there

Comment: our workaround was use `element` instead of `component`. E.g.  `<Route path="/myapp" element={<MyApp />} />`