# react route parse url and pass props to component

Tags: reactjs

I have routes defined like following:

```
<Route path="auth">
   <Route path="confirm-code" component={this.getIndexRoute()} email="xyz@gmail.com" code="1234" />
</Route>
```

`getIndexRoute()` gives me a component to navigate to. When I hit `http://localhost:3000/de/auth/confirm-code/` it works.

However, I want to modify this path to be like `http://localhost:3000/de/auth/confirm-code/email=someEmail&code=someCode` 
I would then want to pass those received email and code as props to my component so that I can process them there. right now I am hard-coding email="xyz@gmail.com" and code=1234. I would like to extract them from the url.

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All query params (email, code) are automatically passed to the component via `props.location` - or depending on which router version you are using you can use `withRouter`
[react-router getting this.props.location in child components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37516919/react-router-getting-this-props-location-in-child-components)