# react-router - Cannot get information in this.props.location

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a app created from create-react-app and the prop location for all my components is always undefined..

Here is index.js

```
    ReactDOM.render((
<BrowserRouter >
<App/>
</BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Here is a short version of app.js

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      auth: UserProfile.getAuth(),
    }

  }

  render() {
    if(this.state.auth){
      return (
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            ...
            <Route path="/editUser" render={()=><EditUser className="App" app={this}/>} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      );
    }

    else{
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

now here is editUser.jsx

```
class EditUser extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
...
}

componentDidMount(){
    console.log(this.props.location) //undefined
  }

render() {
return (<div>...</div>)
```

I keep getting undefined and I dont understand why...
I use `"react-router-dom": "^4.3.1"` according to my package.json

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the router props into the component since you're using the `render` prop of the `<Route/>` component.

Also, In your `App` component you don't need `BrowserRouter as Router` since you're already wrapping `<App/>` in `index.js`. I changed the `import` and removed the wrapping `<Router/>` component.

```
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
    ...
    render() {
        if (this.state.auth) {
            return (
                <Switch>
                    ...
                    <Route path="/editUser" render={props =>
                        <EditUser {...props} className="App" app={this}/>
                    }/>
                </Switch>
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I knew it was a problem with how I handled the router... Anyway thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the withRouter HOC on your EditUser Component in order to inject props like location.

See [react-router getting this.props.location in child components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37516919/react-router-getting-this-props-location-in-child-components)