# Bold active menu after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, antd

I have an application has been written with React + Redux and Antdesign. My application is a dashboard app. So I used the layout in Ant design https://ant.design/components/layout/

When I click on side menus, the active menu gets bold which is fine. But I need when I refresh the page, it checks and detect the route and bold related menu item.

I have a **Sidebar** component which is stateful. Inside it, in componentDidMount I call a function which will dispatch an action from mapDispatchToProps. The reducer changes the state. But in HTML codes, in defaultSelectedKeys, I can not set the number of active menus.

**Sidebar.js component:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Switch, BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

// antd
import { Layout, Breadcrumb, Menu, Icon } from 'antd';
const { Header, Content, Footer, Sider } = Layout;

// Helpers
import { Alert } from '../helpers/notifications';

// Components
import Home from '../components/Home';
// import Header from '../components/Header';
import NotFound from '../components/NotFound';
import PostsEditor from '../components/Posts/PostsEditor';

// Actions
import { setRouteActiveFlag } from '../actions/ui.action'

class Sidebar extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount () {
      const routes = {
        '/'       : 1,
        '/posts'  : 2,
        '/logout' : 3
      }

      this.props.detectActiveRoute(setRouteActiveFlag({
        routes:routes, 
        path:window.location.pathname
      }))
    }


    render() {

        const { selectedRoute } = this.props;
        console.log(selectedRoute);

        return (
            <div>
              <Layout>
                <Sider
                  style={{
                    overflow: 'auto',
                    height: '100vh',
                    position: 'fixed',
                    left: 0,
                  }} 
                  breakpoint="lg"
                  collapsedWidth="0"
                  onBreakpoint={broken => {
                    console.log(broken);
                  }}
                  onCollapse={(collapsed, type) => {
                    console.log(collapsed, type);
                  }}
                >
                  <div className="logo" >
                    Logo <br/><br/><br/>
                  </div>
                  <Menu theme="dark" mode="inline"  style={{ lineHeight: '64px' }} defaultSelectedKeys={[selectedRoute.toString() || '1']}>
                    <Menu.Item key="1">
                      <Link to="/" style={{ color:'#fff' }}>
                        <Icon type="user" />
                        <span className="nav-text">Home</span>
                      </Link>
                    </Menu.Item>
                    <Menu.Item key="2">
                      <Link to="/posts" style={{ color:'#fff' }}>
                        <Icon type="user" />
                        <span className="nav-text">Posts</span>
                      </Link>
                    </Menu.Item>
                    <Menu.Item key="3">
                      <a href="/logout" style={{ color:'#fff' }}>
                        <Icon type="user" />
                        <span className="nav-text">Logout</span>
                      </a>
                    </Menu.Item>
                  </Menu>
                </Sider>
                <Layout style={{ marginLeft: 200 }}>
                  <Content style={{ margin: '24px 16px 0', overflow: 'initial'}}>

                      <Breadcrumb style={{ margin: '0 0 20px 0' }}>
                        <Breadcrumb.Item>Home</Breadcrumb.Item>
                        <Breadcrumb.Item>List</Breadcrumb.Item>
                        <Breadcrumb.Item>App</Breadcrumb.Item>
                      </Breadcrumb>

                      <div style={{ padding: 24, background: '#fff', minHeight: 360 }}>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
                            <Route path="/posts/:id?" component={PostsEditor} />
                            <Route component={NotFound}/>
                        </Switch>
                        <Alert stack={ { limit: 3 } } />
                      </div>

                  </Content>

                  <Footer style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Ant Design ©2018 Created by Ant UED</Footer>
                </Layout>
              </Layout>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return {
      state: state,
      props: ownProps,
      selectedRoute:state.ui.selectedRoute || 1
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
    return {
      detectActiveRoute: (obj) => dispatch(obj)
    }
}


export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Sidebar)
```

ui.action.js

```
export const setRouteActiveFlag = (payload = 'global') => ({
  type: actions.SET_ROUTE_ACTIVE_FLAG,
  payload
});
```

ui.reducer.js

```
import { handleActions } from 'redux-actions';
import Immutable from 'seamless-immutable';
import * as actions from '../consts/action-types';


const initialState = Immutable({
  requests: {},
  selectedRoute:{}
});


export default handleActions({
  [actions.SET_ROUTE_ACTIVE_FLAG]: (state, action) => {
    if (action.payload.routes && action.payload.path && action.payload.routes[ action.payload.path ]) {
        return state.set('selectedRoute', action.payload.routes[ action.payload.path ])
    }else{
        return state.set('selectedRoute', 1)
    }
  }
}, initialState);
```

Please help me find the best and simple practices.

Comment: Upload to sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/new

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-frog-ljffw?from-embed but it still have error

Comment: @SamiAlMorshedi, I added an answer that works when using hooks.

Answer (score 9):

There is no need to use `redux`, just use `react-router` to get current pathname and pass it to `defaultSelectedKeys`.

```
<Menu defaultSelectedKeys={[this.props.location.pathname]}>
  ...
  .....
</Menu>
```

Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37523743/7220129) , if you don't know how to get pathname

Comment: This is not a solution anymore since props.location is undefined. Some suggest using hooks ( useEffect(() => {  return history.listen((location) => { .. ). But this very code doesn't work until the user clicks a BrowserRouter link.

Answer (score 2):

The following answer assumes you are **using hooks**. I know that from your question you are not using hooks, but it could be useful for other people. This answer works not only when refreshing but also when pressing the back and forward buttons:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useHistory, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Layout, Menu } from 'antd'

const { Sider } = Layout

const items = [
  { key: '1', label: 'Invoices', path: '/admin/invoices' },
  { key: '2', label: 'Service Details', path: '/admin/service-details' },
  { key: '3', label: 'Service Contract Details', path: '/admin/service-contract-details' },
  { key: '4', label: 'Cost Centers', path: '/admin/cost-centers' },
  { key: '5', label: 'Clients', path: '/admin/clients' },
  { key: '6', label: 'Vendors', path: '/admin/vendors' }
]

const Sidebar = () => {
  const location = useLocation()
  const history = useHistory()
  const [selectedKey, setSelectedKey] = useState(items.find(_item => location.pathname.startsWith(_item.path)).key)

  const onClickMenu = (item) => {
    const clicked = items.find(_item => _item.key === item.key)
    history.push(clicked.path)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setSelectedKey(items.find(_item => location.pathname.startsWith(_item.path)).key)
  }, [location])

  return (
    <Sider style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
      <h3 style={{ paddingLeft: '1rem', paddingTop: '1rem', fontSize: '1.25rem', fontWeight: 'bold', minHeight: 64, margin: 0 }}>
        Costek
      </h3>
      <Menu selectedKeys={[selectedKey]} mode='inline' onClick={onClickMenu}>
        {items.map((item) => (
          <Menu.Item key={item.key}>{item.label}</Menu.Item>
        ))}
      </Menu>
    </Sider>
  )
}

export default Sidebar
```

Your sidebar will look as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add any css in your menu by conditioning and adding a class just in this way.

```
<MenuItem className={ (this.props.location.pathname==='/yourRoute')? 'active' : '' } >

</MenuItem>
```

**In case if you get any kind of undefined error then you can use the 'withRouter' HOC**

in this way.

In your component where you want to get that location prop, you will first import

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
```

then you can export it in this way.

```
export default withRouter(YourComponent);
```

**Final code can look somewhat similar to this**

```
import React, {Fragment, Component} from 'react';
import {withRouter, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class Menu extends Component {

   render(){

     const {pathname} = this.props.location;

     return (
        <Fragment>
            <div id="sidebar-menu" className="sidebar-menu">

                    <ul>
                        <li className={(pathname==='/dashboard' || pathname==='/')?'active':''}> 
                            <Link to="/dashboard">Dashboard</Link>
                        </li>

                        <li className={(pathname==='/properties')?'active':''}> 
                            <Link to="/properties">Properties</Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

            </div>
        </Fragment>
     );

     }

}
export default withRouter(Menu);
```