# how to use setState in react route?

Tags: reactjs

```
state = { 
      heading:"a"
     }
componentDidUpdate=async(prevProps,prevState)=>{
       if(prevState.heading!==this.state.heading){
         // use this.setState
       }
     }

<Route path="/" exact component={A}/>
<Route path="/b" exact component={B}/>
<Route path="/c" exact component={C}/>
```

I want to change heading to b and c according to the route. I don't know how to use "match" or "params" here in route

Comment: where is your state ?
you have 3 components: A,B & C, but where you holde your state ? in app.js ? index.js ? ... ?

Comment: @BinaryMan in App.js . A,B,C are imported components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as i understand from your code, you want to do something depending on the current route.

The **useLocation** hook returns the current URL as an object:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'


.
.
.
const url = useLocation();
console.log(url.pathname);
.
.
.
```

Comment: how do i use this in class components?

Comment: I can't  use hooks in class component

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37516919/react-router-getting-this-props-location-in-child-components