# location.search is undefined but location is where the application runs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, types

I have this code in my application.

```
const queryString = require('query-string');
const parsed = queryString.parse(location.search);
return this.docListingService.getPacks(parsed.policy).then(packs => {
    this.setState({ isLoading: false, packs });
    return packs;
}).catch((error) => {
    this.loggingService.logError('Error returning Docs ' + error);
    this.setState({ errorOccured: true});
});
```

It doesn't work because `location.search` is `undefined`.

I can see that `location` is `http://localhost:3000/` which is where this application is running. How can/should this be set?

Answer (score 1):

**You can't using dot notaion on strings!**

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37523743/4885936)
You can try this (if you are using react hooks),
first of all define location: `const location = useLocation();`

Answer (score 1):

Try to investigate a little bit:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/search
- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_search.asp

Location search is a funtion that returns the queryString of the url.
you dont have a queryString in your URL
..your/whole/url?queryStringOverHere=something